# route a Route 53 not sending traffic to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I want to route a Route 53 domain to an EC2 instance.

The domain is

> operatica.io

Here is the route53 console with A record:
[image]

I have been following the article below.  I simply create an "A" record and pointing it to the ip address of my ec2 instance.  Is this all I need to do to start seeing my route53 domain pointed to my ec2 instance?

This is precisely what I have done in the past with Godaddy and works without issue.  Am I missing an intermediate step?  Do I need to create a traffic policy?

This domain was purchased on route53 so name servers are setup:
ns-.awsdns-.com. 
ns-.awsdns-.net. 
ns-.awsdns-.co.uk. 
ns-.awsdns-.org.

I have been following this article:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

Comment: Yes, that should be it. Give us the domain so we can take a look.

Comment: Can you show us the Route53 console showing your records?

Comment: @ceejayoz . I added a screenshot of the console.

Answer (score 1):

https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A
does not show an A record for `operatica.io`.
NS setup looks good, but I guess that the A record is still missing

Route53 -> Hosted Zones -> operatica.io -> create record A type, add public EC2 ip.

Comment: the tool shows "no error" and 899 IN SOA ns-1213.awsdns-23.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400 . What part of the response shows there is no A Record?

Comment: Its the fact that the ANSWER section is empty. Try to query anoter site  and see the ANSWER part for comparision.

Comment: @petey The `ANSWER` section is empty. Try `stackoverflow.com` or `fark.com` or whatnot in that tool - you'll see one or more lines in the answer section.

Comment: @hargut . I have attached the console to show the a record present.

Answer (score 1):

The nameservers you've configured for the domain are:

```
ns-420.awsdns-52.com.
ns-1014.awsdns-62.net.
ns-1213.awsdns-23.org.
ns-1584.awsdns-06.co.uk.
```

The nameservers Route53 *told* you (as shown in the screenshot) to configure for the domain are:

```
ns-487.awsdns-60.com.
ns-518.awsdns-00.net.
ns-1080.awsdns-07.org.
ns-2040.awsdns-63.co.uk.
```

This is why your records aren't having any effect. Update your domain at your registrar to point at the correct set of nameservers. Every domain on Route53 has a potentially *different* random set of nameservers - you can't just copy them from another domain and have them work.

Comment: I bought the domain on route53.  You are saying they don't configure them or they are not pointing correctly?

Comment: I don't buy domains on Route53, I just use their DNS, so I'm not sure. Maybe they set a default "parking" set of nameservers when you purchase. Either way, you need to update the domain to point at the right nameservers for the zone in the screenshot.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally created a second zone for the same domain? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-register.html says "If you create records in a hosted zone other than the one that Route 53 creates automatically, you must update the name servers for the domain to use the name servers for the new hosted zone."

Comment: Try to update the nameservers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-register.html#domain-register-other-dns-service-procedure

Comment: This is the first time i've bought on route53.  I set the domain to the name servers you mentioned are "configured".  I think that might work.

Comment: AWS Route53 DNS is very powerful, and definiteley one of the best I've seen. But with that huge amount of options it is sometimes hard to stay on the right path. And one of the things here is, that a hosted zone does not have to be directly linked to a domain. Creating a hosted zone provides nameservers which have to be set at your registrar, which is in this case as well AWS. Once you've updated the nameservers it should work as expected.